# OMNET++, VEINS and SUMO - Vehicle disappear when I try to change color

Tags: simulation, omnet++, veins, sumo

I am trying to change the color of an individual vehicle in SUMO, but when I use the following code,  the vehicle disappears. I am able to get data on the cars, but the vehicle stays invisible.

I put these definitions on the top of this same file

```
#define black TraCIColor(0,0,0,0)
#define red TraCIColor(255,0,0,0)
#define green TraCIColor(0,255,0,0)
#define yellow TraCIColor(255,255,0,0)
#define blue TraCIColor(0,0,255,0)
#define violet TraCIColor(255,0,255,0)
#define cyan TraCIColor(0,255,255,0)
#define white TraCIColor(255,255,255,0)
```

But when I call the function for change color the car disappears.

```
self = getParentModule()->getIndex();
traciVehicle = mobility->getVehicleCommandInterface();
if(self==carId) traciVehicle->setColor(green);
```

[image]

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the variable `green` you are using holds a value different to the one you are expecting. Most likely you would want to store something like the result of `TraCIColor::fromTkColor("green")` here.

Comment: Thanks, but I put the definition on the top of this same file (#define green TraCIColor(0,255,0,0)). However, when I call the function traci→vehicle("1").set Color(green); the car disappears. I edited my question to make more clear.

Comment: You're using an alpha value of `0` (fully transparent). You probably want to use a value of `255` (fully opaque) instead. See the definition of `green` at https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIColor.cc#L322

Comment: Great thanks! I only replaced the definition values for (0, 255, 0, 255) and it worked perfectly.